# NTLM authentication with Scrapy for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am attempting to scrape data from a website that requires authentication.
I have been able to successfully login using requests and HttpNtlmAuth with the following:

```
s = requests.session()     
url = "https://website.com/things"                                                      
response = s.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\USERNAME','PASSWORD'))
```

I would like to explore the capabilities of Scrapy, however I have not been able to successfully authenticate.

I came across the following middleware which seems like it could work but I do not think I have been implementing it properly:

https://github.com/reimund/ntlm-middleware/blob/master/ntlmauth.py

In my settings.py I have

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = { 'test.ntlmauth.NtlmAuthMiddleware': 400, }
```

and in my spider class I have

```
http_user = 'DOMAIN\\USER'
http_pass = 'PASS'
```

I have not been able to get this to work.

If anyone has successfully been able to scrape from a website with NTLM authentication can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was going on.

1: This is considered a "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE" not a "SPIDER_MIDDLEWARE".

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = { 'test.ntlmauth.NTLM_Middleware': 400, }
```

2: The middleware which I was trying to use needed to be modified significantly.  Here is what works for me:

```
from scrapy.http import Response
import requests                                                              
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

class NTLM_Middleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        url = request.url
        pwd = getattr(spider, 'http_pass', '')
        usr = getattr(spider, 'http_user', '')
        s = requests.session()     
        response = s.get(url,auth=HttpNtlmAuth(usr,pwd))      
        return Response(url,response.status_code,{}, response.content)
```

Within the spider, all you need to do is set these variables:

```
http_user = 'DOMAIN\\USER'
http_pass = 'PASS'
```

Comment: Thank you for posting what worked for you, that works perfectly for the authentication. I'll note that to make it work with my spider I had to return `HtmlResponse` instead of just `Response` otherwise `xpath` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @SpaceDog for the comment just above, I faced a similar problem trying to crawl an intranet website using ntlm authentification.  The crawler would just see the first page because LinkExtractor within the CrawlSpider didn't fire up.

Here's my working solution using scrapy 1.0.5

**NTLM_Middleware.py**

```
from scrapy.http import Response, HtmlResponse
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

class NTLM_Middleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        url = request.url
        usr = getattr(spider, 'http_usr', '')
        pwd = getattr(spider, 'http_pass','')
        s = requests.session()
        response = s.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(usr,pwd))
        return HtmlResponse(url,response.status_code, response.headers.iteritems(), response.content)
```

**settings.py**

```
import logging

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'scrapy intranet'

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=16


# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'intranet.NTLM_Middleware.NTLM_Middleware': 200,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware':None
}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapyelasticsearch.scrapyelasticsearch.ElasticSearchPipeline',
}

ELASTICSEARCH_SERVER='localhost'
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=''
ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=''
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX='intranet'
ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE='pages_intranet'
ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY='url'
ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_LEVEL=logging.DEBUG
```

**spiders/intranetspider.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

#from scrapy import log
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule, Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Response

import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class PageItem(scrapy.Item):
    body=scrapy.Field()
    title=scrapy.Field()
    url=scrapy.Field()

class IntranetspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    http_usr='DOMAIN\\user'
    http_pass='pass'
    name = "intranetspider"
    protocol='https://'
    allowed_domains = ['intranet.mydomain.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://intranet.mydomain.ca/']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(),callback="parse_items",follow=True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Crawl de la page %s',response.url)
        item = PageItem()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)

        #remove script tags and javascript from content
        [x.extract() for x in soup.findAll('script')]

        item['body']=soup.get_text(" ", strip=True)
        item['url']=response.url

        return item
```