# Scraping a site with alert window authentification

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a python app that would scrape some data off my university's LMS to check if there are new files and if yes then download them to my local directories.

The access to the page however is secured with my login and password, but there's no such thing as a html login form for that site, it's just an Alert window type popup where I put my login/password (Like the login you usually do when logging into a router), and I'm not sure how to proceed then.

Could someone help me out or point me to some resource on how to authenticate the connection at this type of a site before trying to scrape? Either with mechanize or something else.

Thanks.

Comment: That alert window posts to something. What does your network tab tell you?

Comment: That's HTTP Basic Auth.

Comment: I tried looking to the Network tab but I'm a beginner at this so I'm not sure if I looked correctly. I can't find anything relevant to auth in the list. Could you maybe help me out what to look for ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is a HTTP Basic authorization.
Try if you can login with

`http(s)://(username):(password)@(url)` in your browser's address bar.

If that's the case, 
in `settings.py`, use this to enable the corresponding middleware:

`DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARE = [ 'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware']`

And use the middleware like this this in your spider:

```
class TheSpider(scrapy.Spider):

http_user = 'username'
http_pass = 'password'

def crawl(self, response):
    pass

# do teh magicz!
```

It's in the documentation---See [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/downloader-middleware.html) for details.

Comment: I tried that in the browser and it just said not availible. If i tried it with curl, I could see the Authorization header but the response was 401.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    < Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    < SPRequestGuid: 04cf6ba0-2ac0-4c38-bf72-4570cf806dcc
    < WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
    < X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    < MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6109
    < Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2015 16:11:25 GMT
    < Content-Length: 0

Comment: `401` means "Not Authorized".

Comment: Yes I know that, but the username and password is fine. (sorry about the response formatting, im not sure how to format non-inline code in comments)

Comment: Can you try `curl (url) -v --ntlm --negotiate -u (username):(password)` ?

Comment: According to the `WWW-Authenticate: NTLM` header, it's actually a NTLM authorization. (Like what you're using to log into someone's shared folder on Windows)

Comment: Cool , looks like that worked. It returned a Redirect. So since it is NTLM and not basic http , I should probably use a different middleware right ?

Comment: It's not included in Scrapy. But you can try to figure out how to write a middleware. I've found some [snippets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420135/ntlm-authentication-with-scrapy-for-web-scraping)

Comment: Ok thank you that is really helpful. I'll try to figure it out then :)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested:

I found a way to do this using `beautifulsoup`, `requests` and [`requests_ntlm`](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm) libraries.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  I have literally spent days trying to figure this out.  This package is amazing and perfectly solved my problem!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Near is probably the best option. I've been looking everywhere for a while now and have never been able to get the normal "http://user:pass@url" to work for me. Using the requests_ntlm library is the ONLY thing I've been able to get to work in my particular project so I HIGHLY recommend checking it out if you are having issues with HTTP authentication.